# Diff & Merging between different VCS

Tags: git, svn, merge, diff

I am transferring a old SVN repository to Git. Most of the folders in the SVN-repo are already transferred into a new git repository, with success.

My team is still building on the SVN repo, and I'm also working on the GIT repository. Because the structure on the new repo (git) is totally different (new folders, ect.) it's hard to merge through Tower (mac app).

Is there a way I can use GIT to merge folders?

Example directory structure;

- Folder1 is a git repository
- Folder2 is a folder outside any CSV

Example script;

```
$ diff_merge.sh folder1/ folder2/
```

I've been searching for something like this, but couldn't come up with a relative easy solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ironically, there is a free, platform-independent tool which is called exactly like the shell script you envisioned - *DiffMerge* - which can do exactly that. It's not linked to any version control system so you can diff and merge entire folder trees as you like. I use it quite often for such tasks. Get it [here](https://sourcegear.com/diffmerge/).

Screen shot of the folder diff UI (on Windows):

[image]

Screen shot of the file diff UI (on Mac):

[image]

Screen shot of the file merge UI (on Linux):

[image]